# What does "children__" mean in Django? Where is it documented?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to parse this Django code (without any familiarity with Django, I might add)

```
Question.objects.filter(children__marked=True)
```

I know the model contains a table called "forum_node" with one of the column named "marked". From what I understand, this statement fetches all the questions where any of its children (= answers) are accepted (or "marked"). How does this magic work?

Comment: It's `children__marked`, not `children__`.

Comment: @delnan - I assumed that "children__" is some special prefix, and "marked" is a specific column where this is applied, hence "children__marked".

Comment: No, a name is just a name, regardless of how many e.g. underscores are in it (well, two leading underscores trigger name mangling, but it's still an identifier, albeit now a longer and more obscure one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what happens you should take a closer look at Django's docs explaining the [query options and the object-relational mapping](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

`children` refers to a related model (there should be an according m2m or foreign key field named children on your `question` model, indicating the related model, e.g. `node`) and `marked` is a field on the related model.

Answer (score 2):

The `Node` model probably contains something like:

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='children')
marked = models.BooleanField()
```

The statement:

```
Question.objects.filter(children__marked=True)
```

Is just doing a join on the two tables and returning `Question` models that have at least one `Node` model with `marked=True`.